# Joomla Constant _QQ_ already defined after update to latest version

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I am new in Joomla. I have recently update my version from joomla 2.5 to joomla 3.8.11.

I had replace all files of jomlaa 3.8.11 to root directories.

When I access admin side, It gives me error : [image]

Notice: Constant *QQ* already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs[main_folder]\libraries\src\Language\Language.php on line 18

Anyone master here who can fix it ?

Comment: Hi, first of all, try to find the other occurrence(s) of definition of the constant in your whole project.

Search: "define('_QQ_', '"');" or "define('_QQ_'" in your Joomla! root folder (with help of editor or some file manager) to know on which place the definition is set.

Comment: You might want to try the joomla SE site [joomla.se]

Comment: Did you check this post - https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=955213

Comment: @Elin Thank you for your help. I will check it

Comment: @vrajesh As Elin mentioned, you may wish to create a [JoomlaStackExchange](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/) account and post your question there to reach a more dedicated audience.